# Place label along line near both start and end of line in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to place label at both the start and the end of a polyline in QGIS.
At the moment I'm only able to place a labet either at the start or at the end of my polyline.

I guess I should use the generator geometry

```
line_substring(reverse($geometry),0,1)
line_substring(($geometry),0,1)
```

[image]
How to use those 2 code together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `rule based labeling`.

Create a rule labelling the start point. When done, copy/paste it and instruct to label the end point. In both cases, don't set any filter.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can create a generated geometry as Point / Multipoint type :

```sql
collect_geometries(
    start_point($geometry),
    end_point($geometry)
)
```

---

*Documentation* :

- [collect_geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#collect-geometries)
- [start_point](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#start-point)
- [end_point](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#end-point)